# Confusion about the correlation coefficient

Tags: probability-or-statistics, correlation

If a wooden stick with a length of 1 meter is randomly cut into two sections, what is the correlation coefficient of the length of the two sections?

```
Refine[Correlation[{x, 1 - x}], 1 > x > 0]
```

I use the above code and get a result of `1`, but the answer is `-1`, I want to know what's wrong?

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]; x = RandomReal[1, 1000]; y = 1 - x; Correlation[x, y]` evaluates to `-1.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing a particular sample of size 1 (`{x,1-x}`) and the bivariate random variable $(X, 1-X)$ where $X\sim U(0,1)$.  Also, your use of `{x,1-x}` doesn't appear to be one of the allowed parameter inputs (unless `{x,1-x}` is being considered as a matrix).

I don't see why *Mathematica* gives an answer of 1.  It probably should have complained about the input you gave.

The appropriate answer for your question is to treat $X$ and $1-X$ as random variables:

```
d = TransformedDistribution[{x, 1 - x}, x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
Correlation[d, 1, 2]
(* -1 *)
```

Comment: "I don't see why Mathematica gives an answer of 1. It probably should have complained about the input you gave." Mathematica is just computing the correlation matrix of a sample of 2 scalar observations. Compare `Correlation[{{1}, {2}}]` and `Correlation[{1, 2}]`. Since the observations are 1D, the correlation matrix is 1 x 1 and therefore only has the element 1, which is the diagonal element that's always 1 regardless of the data.